# AfxMessageBox function triggers a click-event twice

Tags: mfc, messagebox

I have an MFC application where an AfxMessageBox is called inside an event handler of a radio-button. As soon as an ‘Yes’, ‘No’ or ‘Cancel’ button is pressed on the message-box to close it, the event handler is called again automatically. This leads to another instance of AfxMessageBox getting called. This time closing the message-box, leads to regular flow.
The ‘auto’ property of radio-button is set to false as per other functionality of my application. I am wondering, why is closing the message-box causing an extra event related to the radio-button event handler.

```
void CMFCApplication3Dlg::OnBnClickedRadio1()
{

    int answer;
    answer = AfxMessageBox(_T("Save Changes?"), MB_YESNOCANCEL);
    CheckRadioButton(IDC_RADIO1,IDC_RADIO2,IDC_RADIO1);
}
```

Here is the sequence of steps:

- Radio button clicked, control comes to the event handler function -
  OnBnClickedRadio1
- MessageBox is displayed (via the AfxMessageBox
  call)
- When Yes, No or Cancel button is pressed, the message box
  disappears but the control comes backs to the OnBnClickedRadio1
  function, without executing the ‘CheckRadioButton’ call.
- The message-box appears a second time.
- When Yes, No or Cancel button is pressed, the message box disappears. This time, ‘CheckRadioButton’
  is executed and the handler exits.

Comment: Your code seems a perfect recipe for an endless recursion disaster. And the second message box is a consequence of you calling `CheckRadioButton`. You should put a breakpoint on it and Step Into it.

Comment: What is `CheckRadioButton` ?